# How to pass an object to a constructor?

Tags: java, object, reference

I have this code

```
import javax.swing.*
import java.util.TimerTask;
public class myClass extends TimerTask{

    JSlider j;        

    // constructor
    public myClass (JSlider j) {
    this.j = j;
        ... do stuff e.g. use "j"...
    }
}
```

How do I now call *myClass* and pass it a JSlider value?

```
JSlider slider0;
new MyClass(slider0);
```

Is all of the above the appropiate way to do it?

Comment: Looks right to me. I would just suggest that, unless you have a good reason not to, declare j as private. Otherwise, it keeps default visibility, which is package-private, meaning any other class in the same package can read it.  
Also, in java, constructors aren't really overridden, since they aren't inherited in the first place.

Comment: Ty jpm, yes it wasn't overridden, I changed the subject title of the question now. Do you know what gets passed over here? Is it slider0, which is a JSlider instance? Is it its value? I didn't yet grap what a value exactly is..

Comment: You should store the instance of MyClass in a variable as explained below. This way you can do something useful with the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided your class looks like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class MyClass extends TimerTask{

    private JSlider j;        

    public MyClass (JSlider j) {
        this.j = j;
    }
}
```

Then your instantiation code should look somewhat like this:

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass(mySlider);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSlider j  = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL,
                                      FPS_MIN, FPS_MAX, FPS_INIT);
new MyClass(j);
```

So as you said.