# Pass argument from a constructor to a constructor of a different class

Tags: java, constructor, parameter-passing

May be a silly question, but I could not find any info on this on the web. How can I pass an argument from the body of the constructor to a constructor of a different class? For example, if I have two classes, A and B:

```
        class A   {
        private Object ob;
        public A(String str)   {
            ob = new Object();
         }
       }

     class B   {
        String str;
        public B(Object object)   {
          // pass Object argument from constructor of class A here.
        }
       }
```

I need to pass variable ob initialized in constructor of class A into the constructor of class B. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You 'pass a variable to a constructor' by calling it with new: `A a = new A(s);`

Comment: What exactly couldn't you find any info on? There's lots of examples of passing parameters to constructors

Comment: Passing objects to constructors is no different from passing objects to methods. One of the 1st results from Google - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486355/how-to-pass-an-object-to-a-constructor

Comment: Well, this link shows how to pass an object to a constructor in a class. This is not what I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a `private B b` in the A class, then just like any other object, you can make a `new B(str)`, and assign it to the field